# How to extract specific <td> from table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a web scraping program using Python & BeautifulSoup. I encountered a problem when scraping a table.

My problem is, I need to extract selected `<td>` tags only and not the entire table.

I only need the numbers for 52 Week High, 52 Week Low, Earnings Per Share and Price to book value.

Is there anyway I can do that?

**Sample Table**

```html
<table id="TABLE_1">
  <tbody id="TBODY_2">
    <tr id="TR_3">
      <td id="TD_4">
        <strong id="STRONG_5">52-Week High:</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_6">
        1,116.00
      </td>
      <td id="TD_7">
        <strong id="STRONG_8">Earnings Per Share TTM (EPS):</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_9">
        47.87 (15.57%)
      </td>
      <td id="TD_10">
        <strong id="STRONG_11">Price to Book Value (P/BV):</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_12">
        2.5481125565
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="TR_13">
      <td id="TD_14">
        <strong id="STRONG_15">52-Week Low:</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_16">
        867.50
      </td>
      <td id="TD_17">
        <strong id="STRONG_18">Price-Earnings Ratio TTM (P/E):</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_19">
        20.8272404429
      </td>
      <td id="TD_20">
        <strong id="STRONG_21">Return on Equity (ROE):</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_22">
        12.42%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="TR_23">
      <td id="TD_24">
        <strong id="STRONG_25">Fair Value:</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_26">
        -
      </td>
      <td id="TD_27">
        <strong id="STRONG_28">Dividends Per Share (DPS):</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_29">
        -
      </td>
      <td id="TD_30">
        <strong id="STRONG_31">Recommendation:</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_32">
        None<span id="SPAN_33"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="TR_34">
      <td id="TD_35">
        <strong id="STRONG_36">Last Price:</strong>
      </td>
      <td id="TD_37">
        <span id="SPAN_38"></span> <span id="SPAN_39">984.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also showed my codes for your reference.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd

myurl = "https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/ac"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(myurl,headers=hdr)

# Open connection to website
uClient = urlopen(req)

# Offloads the content to variable
page_html = uClient.read()

#just closing it
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

table = page_soup.find("div", {"id":"FundamentalAnalysisPanel"}).find("table")

print(table.text)
```

Comment: "The content contained in the site, but not limited to text, images, and design, except as otherwise claimed, may not be copied, displayed, distributed, altered, reproduced, and be part of any manner not governed by Investagrams."

Comment: I'm sorry i accidentally click something and got deleted one comment. anyway, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `findNextSibling` method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/ac')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# specify table parameters for which you want to find values
parameters = ['52-Week High:', '52-Week Low:', 'Earnings Per Share TTM (EPS):', 'Price-Earnings Ratio TTM (P/E):', 'Price to Book Value (P/BV):']

# iterate all <td> tags and print text of the next sibling (with value),
# if this <td> contains specified parameter.
for td in soup.findAll('td'):
     for p in parameters:
         if td.find('strong', text=p) is not None:
             print(td.findNextSibling().text.strip())
```

Result:

```
1,116.00
47.87 (15.57%)
2.5481125565
867.50
20.8272404429
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working already but is there a way, that only the numbers are returned and not the titles (52-week high, earnings per share, etc...)

Comment: got it! Thank you very much Lev for your help!

Comment: @BenDaggers glad to help:)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want

```
    page_soup = soup(req.data.decode('utf-8'))

    #tables = page_soup.find_all('table')
    tables = page_soup.find_all('td')

    df = pd.read_html(str(tables[i]))
```

where `i` is the table you want